# Output of surface grid points each on a single line

Tags: plotting, output-formatting

```
umin=0;umax=6.;vmin=0;vmax=4.5;nu=10;nv=4;
HyparGrid=Flatten[Table[{u+v,u-v,-u v/6.},{u,umin,umax,(umax-umin)/(nu+1)},{v,vmin,vmax,(vmax-vmin)(nv+1)}]]//TableForm
    ParametricPlot3D[{u+v,u-v,-u v/6.},{u,0,6.},{v,0.,4.5},Mesh->{nu,nv}]
```

Can you please help output the point (x,y,z) coordinates on a single line? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for `Flatten[Table[...], 1]`?

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks @ MarcoB !

Comment: Don't include `TableForm` in the definition of `HyparGrid`. Use parentheses to isolate it, i.e., `(HyparGrid = Flatten[Table[{u + v, u - v, -u v/6.}, {u, umin, umax, (umax - umin)/(nu + 1)}, {v, vmin, vmax, (vmax - vmin) (nv + 1)}], 1]) // TableForm`

Comment: Thank you, @BobHanlon.

Answer (score 3):

- To get all the mesh points, `Subdivide` is convenient

```
Clear[HyparGrid];
umin = 0; umax = 6.; vmin = 0; vmax = 4.5; nu = 10; nv = 4;
HyparGrid = 
  Table[{u + v, u - v, -u v/6.}, {u, 
    Subdivide[umin, umax, nu + 1]}, {v, 
    Subdivide[vmin, vmax, nv + 1]}];
HyparGrid = Flatten[HyparGrid, 1];
Show[ParametricPlot3D[{u + v, u - v, -u v/6.}, {u, 0, 6.}, {v, 0., 
   4.5}, Mesh -> {nu, nv}], 
 Graphics3D[{Red(* AbsolutePointSize[8]*), Ball[HyparGrid, .15]}]]
```

- The original code have typo. `(vmax-vmin)(nv+1)` should be `(vmax-vmin)/(nv+1)`

```
umin = 0; umax = 6.; vmin = 0; vmax = 4.5; nu = 10; nv = 4;
HyparGrid = 
  Table[{u + v, u - v, -u v/6.}, {u, umin, 
    umax, (umax - umin)/(nu + 1)}, {v, vmin, 
    vmax, (vmax - vmin)/(nv + 1)}];
HyparGrid = Flatten[HyparGrid, 1];
Show[ParametricPlot3D[{u + v, u - v, -u v/6.}, {u, 0, 6.}, {v, 0., 
   4.5}, Mesh -> {nu, nv}], 
 Graphics3D[{Red(*AbsolutePointSize[8]*), Ball[HyparGrid, .15]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Neatly demarcated region with grid-points !